# Walk through a form in javascript and check for blank inputs?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I apologize for asking such a "noob" question but I'm outside my area of expertise here.

I'm using Dojo 1.9 and I need to walk through a submitted form and determine if any of the input fields are blank.   The tricky part is that the form is dynamic, it can contain an array of child elements of each array element, with names like `itemList[1].myName`:

```
<form id="businessReferences" action="/yabba/dabba/doo" method="post">
    <input id="itemList[0].myName" name="itemList[0].myName" type="text" value=""/>
    <input id="itemList[0].myAddress" name="itemList[0].myAddress" type="text" value=""/>
    <input id="itemList[1].myName" name="itemList[1].myName" type="text" value=""/>
    <input id="itemList[1].myAddress" name="itemList[1].myAddress" type="text" value=""/>
    <input id="itemList[2].myName" name="itemList[2].myName" type="text" value=""/>
    <input id="itemList[2].myAddress" name="itemList[2].myAddress" type="text" value=""/>
</form>
```

What is the best way to walk through this form and check to see if all the fields for each parent element are empty?  For example if all the fields for `itemList[2]` are empty?   Is there a particular method for doing this?   Seems like it would be a fairly common problem but I haven't been able to track down an answer.

Comment: add a required attrib to your inputs and use css/QSA to select.

Comment: How is the form submitted? There is no submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an submit button in the form

```
    <form id="businessReferences" action="/yabba/dabba/doo" method="post"  onsubmit="return validate()">
        <input id="itemList[0].myName" name="itemList[0].myName" type="text" value=""/>
        <input id="itemList[0].myAddress" name="itemList[0].myAddress" type="text" value=""/>
        <input id="itemList[1].myName" name="itemList[1].myName" type="text" value=""/>
        <input id="itemList[1].myAddress" name="itemList[1].myAddress" type="text" value=""/>
        <input id="itemList[2].myName" name="itemList[2].myName" type="text" value=""/>
        <input id="itemList[2].myAddress" name="itemList[2].myAddress" type="text" value=""/>
        <input type='submit' value="Submit"/> <!-- to trigger validation on this button click -->
    </form>
```

Javscript for validation , it will account for dynamically added element also

```
      <script type='text/javascript'>
    function validate(){
               FromRef = document.getElementById('businessReferences');
     for(i=0; i<FromRef.elements.length; i++)
        {

           if((FromRef.elements[i].value).trim() ==""){  // see if the value is blank popup and alert
             alert( FromRef.elements[i].name +"is required");  
             return false; // not to submit form
           }



        return true;//submit form
    }
     </script>
```

Comment: It would be much more efficient to store a reference to the *elements* collection, rather than getting *document.getElementById('businessReferences').elements* multiple times.